# Odd behavior using the IBM DB2 for i5/OS .NET provider dll in C#

Tags: c#, .net, database, dll, ibm-midrange

At my company we use the IBM DB2 for i5/OS .NET provider dll version 12.0.7.3. in a web application that makes database calls to the iSeries. We encountered a situation where a method which would create a connection then pass that connection to subroutines would seem to access the wrong data sometimes. An example case is as follows: Assume the server has just spun up. Client A calls the "GetContractPdf" and it succeeds. Client B then calls the same method and it fails. The server is restarted and Client B calls the "GetContractPdf" method which then succeeds. Client A calls it and it fails.

I pulled my hair out trying to figure this out but it appears that the code isn't disposing of or handling the database connections properly. It is reproducible in my development environment and when I do reproduce it the connection object shows the right library list for the client that I used to call it, but after inserting a test query that would yield data that could easily identify the client database being touched it was absolutely getting the wrong data. The databases in question are running on the same physical AS/400 machine with different library lists. A third client who has their own AS/400 is unaffected by this problem.

I have been changing any method that accepts a connection as an argument to create their own connection and hoped that it won't cause too big of a performance hit.

Here is the method that generates the connections:

```
  public static iDB2Connection GetConnection(string ClientCode)
    {
        string decrypted = "";
        try
        {
            decrypted = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ClientCode].ConnectionString;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new FaultException(string.Format("Client connection string not found for {0}.", ClientCode));
        }
        try
        {
            decrypted = EncryptDecrypt.Decrypt(decrypted);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new FaultException(string.Format("Error determining connection string for client {0}.", ClientCode));
        }
        try
        {
            return new iDB2Connection(decrypted);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new FaultException("Error accessing database.");
        }
    }
```

And here is some pseudocode that shows how it is used when the problem behavior arises:

```
public static ContractObject GetContract(clientCode,contractId){
 using(iDb2Connection conn = GetConnection(clientCode)){
    ContractObject contractObject = new ContractObject(){
      Id = contractId
    };
    GetSomeData(contractObject,conn);
    GetOtherData(contractObject,conn);
    return contractObject;
 }
}
public static void GetSomeData(ContractObject contract, iDb2Connection    connection){
    string commandText = "Select data from table where conditions";
    using(iDb2Command cmd = new iDb2Command(commandText,connection)){
      using(iDb2DataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()){
         if(reader.HasRows){
             contract.Foo = reader["ColumnName"].ToString();
         }
      }
    }
 }
 public static void GetOtherData(ContractObject contract, iDb2Connection    connection){
    string commandText = "Select data from table where conditions";
    using(iDb2Command cmd = new iDb2Command(commandText,connection)){
      using(iDb2DataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()){
         if(reader.HasRows){
             contract.Bar = reader["ColumnName"].ToString();
         }
      }
    }
 }
```

If I change the methods up so that a new connection object is created for every query the behavior is eliminated.

As I see it there are two possible problems, either I have done something horribly wrong (which I certainly could have), or the IBM dll does not handle passing around connection objects well (which you would think is less likely but could happen). I'm sure there are other possibilities that I'm too inexperienced / code blind to see.

Do any of you have any ideas of what could be causing this behavior or questions that could lead us to figuring out what causes this behavior?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: I've seen funny stuff happen when there's two layers of connection pooling going on.  Such as in the app itself and in the application server.